# UITableView blank

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, plist

Thought I was on a roll and then fell flat on my face again.

After inserting my code to sort plist data into sections, my tableview is showing blank. 
For note, I have reconnected dataSource and delegate, and know the prepareForSegue is not right - once I have the cells showing I will be updating that (was working without sections). 
It's obviously me but I can't see the error and it is building fine.

Ps: I am aware it is not optimised for memory management. Once tableview is working I shall be declaring a keys property and sorting them into that, etc. 
Also, the reason there is no NSLog statements is that my XCODE will not output anything in the console.

Thanks

```
#import "RCViewController.h"
#import "detailView.h"

@interface RCViewController ()

@end

@implementation RCViewController

@synthesize orderedPlistWords, tableView;
@synthesize alphabeticallySortedWords;

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell Identifier";

-(NSDictionary *)alphabeticallySortedWords:(NSArray *)wordsArray {
    NSMutableDictionary *buffer = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in orderedPlistWords) {
        NSString *word = [dict objectForKey:@"Word"];
        NSString *firstLetter = [[word substringToIndex:1]uppercaseString];

        if ([buffer objectForKey:firstLetter]) {
            [(NSMutableArray *)[buffer objectForKey:firstLetter]addObject:dict];
        }
        else {
            NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:dict, nil];
            [buffer setObject:mutableArray forKey:firstLetter];
        }
    }
    NSArray *keys = [buffer allKeys];
    for (int j; j<keys.count; j++) {
        NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:j];
        [(NSMutableArray *)[buffer objectForKey:key]sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    }
    NSDictionary *result = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:buffer];
    return result;

}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    NSArray *keys = [self.alphabeticallySortedWords allKeys];
    return [keys count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];




    NSArray *unsortedKeys = [self.alphabeticallySortedWords allKeys];
    NSArray *sortedKeys = [unsortedKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSString *key = [sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
    NSArray *wordsForSection = [[self.alphabeticallySortedWords objectForKey:key]objectForKey:@"Word"];
    NSString *word = [wordsForSection objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [cell.textLabel setText:word];

    return cell;

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSArray *unsortedKeys = [self.alphabeticallySortedWords allKeys];
    NSArray *sortedKeys = [unsortedKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSString *key = [sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *wordsForSection = [[self.alphabeticallySortedWords objectForKey:key]objectForKey:@"Word"];
    return  [wordsForSection count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:cell];
}


-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *keys = [[self.alphabeticallySortedWords allKeys]sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    return key;
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        detailView *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        destViewController.word = [[self.orderedPlistWords objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Word"];
        destViewController.definition = [[self.orderedPlistWords objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Definition"];
    }
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"words" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Word" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];


    NSMutableArray *plistWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    self.orderedPlistWords = [plistWords sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Word</key>
        <string>Pitch</string>
        <key>Definition</key>
        <string>Ground players play on</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Word</key>
        <string>Goal</string>
        <key>Definition</key>
        <string>Point awarded when ball crosses goal line</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Word</key>
        <string>Yellow Card</string>
        <key>Definition</key>
        <string>Penalise player for foul</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a property, `alphabeticallySortedWords` that your `UITableViewDataSource` methods reference, but that you never populate. You have a similarly named method, `alphabeticallySortedWords`, but that takes an array parameter.

Whenever you have problems like this. Put breakpoints in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView`. That will confirm that these methods are getting called at all (i.e. make sure your scene's base class was set properly, make sure that you've set the data source for the table view property, etc.). In this case, if you had done that, you would have immediately discovered that `alphabeticallySortedWords` was `nil`.

---

By the way, there are other bugs here, too:

In `numberOfRowsInSection`, you have a line that says:

```
NSArray *wordsForSection = [[self.alphabeticallySortedWords objectForKey:key] objectForKey:@"Word"];
```

It should be:

```
NSArray *wordsForSection = [self.alphabeticallySortedWords objectForKey:key];
```

Likewise in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you have lines that say:

```
NSArray *wordsForSection = [[self.alphabeticallySortedWords objectForKey:key] objectForKey:@"Word"];
NSString *word = [wordsForSection objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

They should be:

```
NSArray *wordsForSection = [self.alphabeticallySortedWords objectForKey:key];
NSString *word = [[wordsForSection objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"Word"];
```

In both of those situations, you are extracting `Word` at the wrong time.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I removed the parameter and it has run. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Well, you have a method that you've written that builds this structure, `alphabeticallySortedWords:`, so (a) call that routine after you finish reading the plist; and (b) change that routine to actually save the results into your similarly named property. Frankly, I'd also change the name of that method to eliminate any confusion between the property and the method that builds that property.

Comment: By removing the parameter from the method, the app runs as planned. However, to do this, is that wrong - should I be calling the method in viewdidload? I'm sorry if I'm waffling - I really appreciate the help ☺

Comment: I agree that if you remove the parameter that the code magically works. The problem is that you call this `alphabeticallySortedWords` several times, and you probably don't want to be rebuilding this structure every time. It's fine when you have 3 words defined, but that approach is not scalable. That's why I suggested that you want to (a) keep that method, (b) rename it to avoid confusion with the property, (c) change it to save the results in the `alphabeticallySortedWords` property; and (d) make sure you call this method after you load the plist, so that the property gets set correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your advice